# Need to Initialization js after ajax response magento 2

Tags: magento2, script, initialize-script

I am working on ajaxscroll product but when i got response below script not initialize

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
                "catalogAddToCart": {}
            }
        }

</script>
```

Can anyone help me to initialize script after response.

Comment: which ajaxscroll extension have you used?

Comment: I am creating my own. In first page product ajax addto cart working but in ajax response it is not working

Comment: I got same issue, did you solve this problem?

Comment: Yes I have solved this issue by adding addtocart require function in my page it is not a proper way but it's temporary solution for me

Comment: @Dmitry I have resolved issue try with it. It is working for me.

Comment: @PrashantValanda mind sharing your solution?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya, I am using Lof_Ajaxscroll, facing the same issue, can you pls provide me the fix

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have resolved this issue using below code:

```
htmlObject=jQuery("#custom_search_autocomplete").html(result);  

htmlObject.find('[data-role=autocompletesearch-tocart-form], .form.map.checkout').attr('data-mage-init', JSON.stringify({'catalogAddToCart': {}}));             
htmlObject.trigger('contentUpdated');
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, how did you resolve this issue? I need to re-init add to cart function

Answer (score 14):

I have the same issue and I resolved it by calling catalogAddToCart after the ajax call.

Here is the code snippet

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'html',
    type: 'GET',
    url:url,
    success: function(data){
        var data =  $($.parseHTML(data));
        var productList = data.find('.products.list').html(); 
        productWrapper.append(productList);
        // this solved the problem
        $( "form[data-role='tocart-form']" ).catalogAddToCart(); 
    },
});
```

Comment: Thanks it work for me. **$( "form[data-role='tocart-form']" ).catalogAddToCart();**

Comment: It's give me error TypeError: $(...).catalogAddToCart is not a function

Comment: make sure you are using catalogAddToCart()  after it is defined.

Comment: @ArunKarnawat, Where to add this code? In which file? I am using infinite scroll,

Comment: Wow u saved my day and thanks for this code $( "form[data-role='tocart-form']" ).catalogAddToCart(); Really helpful.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).catalogAddToCart is not a function I GOT THIS ERROR. Where to add this code..

Comment: thanks, it's solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

From the accepted answer I made this generic solution which is a bit easier to understand:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {

    $('[data-mage-init]').each(function() {
        var mageInit = $(this).attr('data-mage-init');

        if (typeof mageInit !== 'undefined') {
            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.type = "text/x-magento-init";
            script.text = '{"*":' + mageInit.trim() + '}';
            $(this)[0].appendChild(script);
            $(this).trigger('contentUpdated');
            $(this).removeAttr('data-mage-init');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: What is element? it's not working. is your code complete?

Answer (score 1):

Example below:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'html',
    type: 'GET',
    url:url,
    success: function(data){
..............
**$('body').trigger('contentUpdated');**
    },
});
```