# magento 2 Add to cart popup is not working after load the product using infinite ajax scroll

Tags: magento-2.1, ajax, jquery

I have used infinite ajax scrolling on product listing page.Its working but there are one issue.

Add to cart popup is not working after load product using infinite ajax scrolling.

Please check bellow URL:

https://magento.minidisc.com.au/headphones/open-headphones

Thanks

Comment: I have same issue

Comment: Can you add add to cart button code. I mean the JS code which is running after hitting the add to cart button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add this code to your ajax scroll function ajax call. It will work for you. Here is reference URL: [Reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122458/need-to-initialization-js-after-ajax-response-magento-2)

```
$( "form[data-role='tocart-form']" ).catalogAddToCart();
```

Comment: TypeError: jQuery(...).catalogAddToCart is not a function

Comment: Same error faced  TypeError: jQuery(...).catalogAddToCart is not a function

Comment: @Jalpesh Patel, I am also facing the same issue, using Lof infinite scroll