# How to re init ajax add to cart inside the response in magento2

Tags: magento2, ajax, product-list, initialize-script

I have installed third-party module Infinite scroll for the lazy load(Lof_Ajaxscroll).

The problem I am facing is Once the page loads new HTML content is generated from ajax. So add to cart is not working at that time. It refreshes the page and adding.

I need to add the product without refreshing.

I checked with extension provider, They are asking to re-init the add to cart inside the response.

My question is How can I re-init the add to cart function inside the ajax response?

Tried below solution but that didn't work in my case.

[Need to Initialization js after ajax response magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122458/need-to-initialization-js-after-ajax-response-magento-2)

Can anyone suggest me, please...

Comment: why aren't you asking this the extension provider?

Comment: @PhilippSander, Extension provider suggesting to add re init code in some file(given the file path), but code should be added by our self, already i checked with them.

Comment: Is this a Land of Coder module?

Comment: @harri,yes land of coder module it is

Comment: Not a fan myself of those modules have had a few problems in past but usually the support will tell you to update a certain file in a botch way if you just ask they are quick at responding. There will be a file inside view/frontend/web/js somewhere and in the success of the ajax call you want to add $("form[data-role='tocart-form']").catalogAddToCart(); i think

Comment: @harri, they suggested the path, but code we need to add, they suggested to add in phtml not in js, i added $("form[data-role='tocart-form']").catalogAddToCart(); where they suggested but its not working

Comment: Hmm i think it needs to run on success otherwise the later addtocart buttons added via ajax wont initalise.

Comment: so, what is your suggestion for it now, how to resolve this conflict?

Comment: Ill have to have a look at the module one min.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89243/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-harri).

Comment: @harri, can you pls make a try once at your end?

Comment: I can only have a brief look right now but i would first try it about line 404 of Lof\AjaxScroll\view\frontend\web\js\script.js afrer self.fire('rendered', [items]);

Comment: Make sure all local cache are flushed after you ammend that file as chrome will cache the old one

Comment: @harri, not cleared with your comment, I need to add ("form[data-role='tocart-form']").catalogAddToCart();  in line num 404 and check?

Comment: Yeah or about 410 after the promise.done section.

Comment: Awesome glad it worked, could you check my answer is how you achieved ( i did not test) and accept please .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the file `Lof\AjaxScroll\view\frontend\web\js\script.js` from the module adding the below code to **line 410** should help fix the ajax issue.

```
$("form[data-role='tocart-form']").catalogAddToCart();
```

It would be better to override this file from within your theme by placing the updated file in the below location until this is addressed properly by Land of Coder.

```
`Lof_AjaxScroll/web/js/script.js`
```

Make sure to clear any local caches and that should initialise the add to cart buttons once the ajax has loaded the new products.

`this.render` function should look like below once done:

```
    this.render = function(items, callback) {
        var self = this,
            $lastItem = this.getLastItem(),
            count = 0;

        var promise = this.fire('render', [items]);

        promise.done(function() {
            $(items).hide(); // at first, hide it so we can fade it in later

            $lastItem.after(items);

            $(items).fadeIn(400, function() {
                // complete callback get fired for each item,
                // only act on the last item
                if (++count < items.length) {
                    return;
                }

                self.fire('rendered', [items]);

                if (callback) {
                    callback();
                }
            });
        });
        $("form[data-role='tocart-form']").catalogAddToCart();
    };
```

Comment: Great solution!!!

Comment: Thanks! A lot of these issues can happen with ajax not initalising properly be careful of swatches also if you are using them.

Comment: So you feel, its not a good solution?

Comment: No It fixes your problem fine I think but i'm just saying in that past swatches have also stopped working on ajax infinite products so test that module on swatches too i guess if your using them. I have not tested that module but if the add to cart buttons don't work it makes me concerned about swatches also as i think they are also initialised on page load so may have same problem.

Comment: this have one problem, once the product filtered after selecting the left nav items, again it re-init, so all products loads again

Comment: Ah so this is a ajax filtered navigation aswell as an infinite scroll? It will be similar again in that we need to check a JS file that loads the response and do the same again there.

Comment: hi @harri, can you please look into it and provide me the fix??

Comment: Maybe ask another question I would need more details. Is this module what has given the ajax layered navigation functionality?

Comment: now this is infinite scroll, other is bss_layered navigation

Comment: I guess ask a question about that as that seems completely seperate and am not sure what it is.

Comment: hi @harri, here is my new question. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261738/re-init-ajax-add-to-cart-inside-the-response-conflict-in-magento2